# How to Check PageLoaded and ModelLoaded?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

How to Check PageLoaded and ModelLoaded?

I tried to check and read each line of code to see where the error was, but in reality everything gradually became complicated and I couldn't control it. So I decided to find a way to test PageLoaded && ModelLoaded. But I don't know the exact way to do this.

I have a Xaml page, this page BindingContext with Model C# code behind:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using NameProject.Models;

namespace NameProject.Pages;
public partial class AlertPage : Popup
{
    AlertModel alertmodel;
    public AlertPage(AlertModel alertmodel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = alertmodel;
        this.alertmodel = alertmodel;
        alertmodel.Alertpage = this;
    }
}
```

In the Model I have an intArray property, this property will always have a value passed in every time the Xaml page is created so make sure it is never Empty.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using NameProject.Pages;
namespace NameProject.Models
{
    public partial class AlertModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public AlertModel() => test();
        void test()
        {
            //await Task.Delay(2000);
            //if (Indexcontrol != null)
            //{
                foreach (int item in Indexcontrol)
                {
                    if (item == 1) Showcontrolred = true;
                }
            //}
            //else return;
        }
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int[]? indexcontrol;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private AlertPage? alertpage;
```

On the Model's Constructors I work with intArray Indexcontrol variables. The problem is that Constructors on the Model always cannot see the values of the Indexcontrol and throw a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

If I remove Comment Task.Delay(2000) and change function to async Task it works perfectly. But this is actually incorrect if PageLoaded && ModelLoaded does the job slower than 2000 milliseconds. And I also don't want to use async Task because this job is not needed yet. I'm only using it temporarily for debugging purposes.

I tried testing Page Loaded but it was really troublesome because I had to access the Functions from the Model.

I tried declaring the PageLoaded function in the Constructor Model but it caused an error.

Problem: What is the best and simplest way to test both PageLoaded and ModelLoaded on a Model?

Comment: Not really an answer, but it seems odd that the model has a reference to the page. That probably indicates something wrong with the design.

Comment: @StayOnTarget I need a reference to the page so I can use the Alertpage.showPopup commands inherited from CommunityToolkit. Use it right on the Model without having to write codeBehind on PageC#. I don't know the exact way to do this if you know please tell me. It's working now but there seems to be a real problem with design errors as you said.

Comment: You don't have to use the reference to the page in the viewmodel. You can get the page in the viewmodel such as `App.Current.MainPage` or `Navigation.NavigationStack.First`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlertPage: Popup
```

has a Method called Opened. This method will always ensure **ModelLoaded && PageLoaded**. This is similar to **PageLoaded**.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using NameProject.Models;

namespace NameProject.Pages;
public partial class AlertPage : Popup
{
    AlertModel alertmodel;
    public AlertPage(AlertModel alertmodel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = alertmodel;
        this.alertmodel = alertmodel;
        alertmodel.Alertpage = this;
        Opened += AlertPage_Opened;
    }
    public void AlertPage_Opened(object? sender, PopupOpenedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something you want
    }
}
```

So now I have fixed my problem. But I have to execute the code in Page's C# CodeBehind, because when I use the Page reference on the Model and call the Opened += PageOpended method; It will cause uninitialized page error. This doesn't seem right with MVVM gathering all the code behind the page in 1 place in the Model. But temporarily had to use it to solve my problem hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to fix here.

First this "async Task" you want to call in your constructor. You should not. Time consuming operation have no place there.

Even more - this is transient injected popup, and its constructor is used for the page to be constructed. I do not know how it is on windows/mac, but on mobile this is a definitely no.

And second, there are many ways to invoke a code in your page. (That code should not be in the page at first place, but anyway). One is the messaging system in the community toolkit.

If you do not understand what I am saying, put a breakpoint at the first line of your constructor, and notice how when you call `test()` the page field is not set. Do not move it from a constructor to a method and swap places, because even if set, the page will not be constructed yet.